# Generate survey forms with dynamic and unique barcode

Tags: forms, devexpress, barcode, acrobat

I want to do the survey with questionnaire forms. I want a function to generate and add a unique barcode to the new form OR everytime I finish and save the form and send one copy to the customer. Its means that the barcode is unique for each customer. How can I do that with a little bit knowledge of programming with VBA in Microsoft Word, or Visual Studio with component user interface such as DevExpress or Telerik?
I know Adobe Acrobat has a function to add barcode but this barcode is not dynamic.

What do you recommend?

Thank you for all suggestions!

Kind regards

Will

Answer (score 0):

what kind of "page" do you mean?
asp.net web page?
or acrobat reader pdf file with survey?

here is devexpress [barcode demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxDocumentServerDemos/BarCode/BarCodeVisualization.aspx)
you can integrate it into the web page or export to image and insert into the adobe acrobat pdf file.

also, i can suggest you to generate survey by using the [xtrareport](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos/ReportTypes/PollingReport)
you can also integrate unique [barcode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument1313) into that report.